# AWS Cloud 9 running 2 servers autodesk forge project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, autodesk-forge, forge

I am working on an autodesk forge project from this repository : https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app that I need to run on my cloud 9 environment. For this project, I have 2 servers to run so it has to be different PORT, that is why I have te first server in localhost:8080 and the second on localhost:8081 that I've changed on shared/config/Siteconfig for localDev. The issue is that cloud 9 has his own localhost adresses and PORT so it gives me a connection error :

GET https://172.31.27.84:8081/dist/main.bundle.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

GET https://172.31.27.84:8081/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The reference app is meant to showcase the different features of the [Data Visualization Extensions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/overview/) when running locally. It's not designed to be deployable to different cloud hosting providers. I would suggest that you only use https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app as a (well) reference :) and add the Data Viz extensions to your own Forge application which will run on a single port.